# Why is my React form not updating dynamically?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am fairly new to software development. I am currently working on a project on Codecademy where the cat should copy what you say, unless it has the tape over it's mouth (pic attached). After many hours, I just can't seem to find why whatever I type into the input field, doesn't dynamically update in the p field. Any guidance would be appreciated!

This is also my first Stack Overflow post, so if I am missing anything, please let me know.

Both states of the cat - without tape, it should copy what is in the input field and vice versa

[image: Both states of the cat - without tape, it should copy what is in the input field and vice versa]

```js
// CopyCat.js

import React from 'react';
import { styles } from '../styles';

const images = {
  copycat: 'https://content.codecademy.com/courses/React/react_photo_copycat.png',
  quietcat: 'https://content.codecademy.com/courses/React/react_photo_quietcat.png'
};


export class CopyCat extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const copying = this.props.copying;
    const toggleTape = this.props.toggleTape;
    const input = this.props.input;
    const handleChange = this.props.handleChange;
    
    return (
      <div style={styles.divStyles}>
        <h1 style={{ marginBottom: 80 }}>Copy Cat</h1>
        <input 
          type='text'
          value={this.input}
          onChange={this.handleChange} />
        <img 
          alt='cat'
          src={copying ? images.copycat : images.quietcat}
          onClick={toggleTape}
          style={styles.imgStyles}
        />
        <p>{this.copying && this.input}</p>
      </div>
    );
  };
}

// CopyCatContainer.js

import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { CopyCat } from '../components/CopyCat';

const images = {
  copycat: 'https://content.codecademy.com/courses/React/react_photo_copycat.png',
  quietcat: 'https://content.codecademy.com/courses/React/react_photo_quietcat.png'
};


class CopyCatContainer extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = { 
      copying: true,
      input: ''
    };

    this.toggleTape = this.toggleTape.bind(this);
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(e) {
    this.setState({input: e.target.value})
  }

  toggleTape() {
    this.setState({copying: !this.state.copying})
  }
  
  render() {
    const copying = this.state.copying;
    const toggleTape = this.toggleTape
    
    return (
      <CopyCat
        copying={this.state.copying}
        toggleTape={this.toggleTape} />
    );
  };
}


ReactDOM.render(<CopyCatContainer />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

Comment: Guidance: add a console.log in handleChange to see if it's called and the event structure.

If nothing appears try to put a simpler function in your component to see if it's called.

From what I read your code seems to follow the logic I would expect to see.

Comment: [Is this](https://codesandbox.io/s/withered-paper-e648l?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark) what you are trying to achieve? Problem in your code is that you need to pass `input` and `handleChange` prop to the `CopyCat` component and in `CopyCat` component, change `<p>{this.copying && this.input}</p>` to `<p>{copying && input}</p>`

Answer (score 1):

You are not passing the input and the handleChange method as props to the CopyCat component

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass input to `<CopyCat />` component like below;

```
return (
  <CopyCat
    copying={this.state.copying}
    toggleTape={this.toggleTape}
    input={this.state.input}  />
);
```

Answer (score 0):

you are not passing handlechange function to copycat component. Pass it and it should work fine. Hope this would help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass both `input` as well as `handleChange` props to  `CopyCat` component to reflect text change, like this:

```
render() {
    const copying = this.state.copying;
    const input = this.state.input;
    
    return (
      <CopyCat
        copying={copying}
        input={input}
        toggleTape={this.toggleTape}
        handleChange={this.handleChange} />
    );
  };
```